# Default string format in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, cultureinfo, currentculture, currentuiculture

I've got a double, for example

```
double d = 4.323d;
```

And I want to display it in a TextBlock on a Silverlight 4 application, but the display should be this:

`4.32`

And I cannot change the StringFormat on the binding whatsoever.

The exception is that if the number is this:

```
double d2 = 4d;
```

Then it should display

`4`, not `4.00`.

And the worst exception is that it should take in account the current UI culture, which implies that if the app is deployed in the US it should use a `.` as a decimal seperator, and in Europe it should use a `,` (well not in the UK, but you get the point...)

I could set the defaultformat to `#.##` IF I were able to change the StringFormat, but I want to do it through CultureInfo

Comment: It might help if you backed up the statement "And I cannot change the StringFormat on the binding whatsoever" since that smacks of something odd which may affect the solution you might end up using.

Comment: Also the spec is a little weak what is the format for 4.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to assume for the moment that you believe you can't use StringFormat in binding because it doesn't use `CultureInfo`.  That being the case add these two usings to your user control code behind :-

```
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Threading;
```

and then add this to its constructor:-

```
Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

Now a binding with `StringFormat=#.##` will use the appropriate decimal separator for the current culture.